# HTML - placing the audio object in top right corner

Tags: html, css

I need to place the `<audio>` in top right corner. How to do it?
I tried with the `<object>` but then I get black bars around the audio player.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <style>
  </style>
</head>
<center>
  <body style="background-color: brown">
    <h1 style="color:white; font-size:80px">Hello</h1>
    <p style="font-size:50px">I like <span style="color:green">turtlez</p>
      <audio controls>
        <source src="hello.mp3" align="right" type="audio/mpeg">
      </audio>
  </body>
</center>
```

Comment: There are number of ways to answer this but, you really should specify what the frontend looks like.

Comment: @WesleyLachenal This is how it looks, and I want to move the red object to the green field: http://i.imgur.com/QbAaBQj.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this code :

```css
audio {
  float: right;
  margin-top:0;
}
```

```html
<audio controls src="http://media.w3.org/2010/07/bunny/04-Death_Becomes_Fur.oga">
  Your user agent does not support the HTML5 Audio element.
</audio>
```

Make sure your src file is included.
Hope it works.

Comment: This is exactly what I have... Why do you even post this?

Comment: @Omnitored I'm sorry i forgot to attach the css.

audio {
  float: right;
  margin-top:0;
}

Comment: okay, i make it for you @Omnitored in fiddle. check it out https://jsfiddle.net/pew2h5qL/

Answer (score 1):

Place your audio element into a container, then align the container.

E.g.

```
<div class="container">
<audio controls>
  <source src="hello.mp3" align="right" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
</div>

.container {
max-width:200px;
position:absolute;
top:0;
right:0;
}
```